# Sincronia do time() PHP e JavaScript

Tags: php, javascript, time

se eu gerar um `time()` no PC comprado no Brasil ele vai resultar um time de acordo com nossa hora e tal, se eu repetir o processo na China, EUA ou qualquer outro local com um PC local o `time()` vai ser diferente. Minhas dúvidas sao:

Como definir que o time() resulte o time() dos EUA por exemplo?

Como definir o meu `tipo` de time() pelo javascript para ele mandar pro PHP e adaptar o time()?

Tipo eu to acessando um servidor onde o time() se refere a hora o Brasil, mas meu time() se refere ao EUA e eu quero avisar o servidor (atraves do JavaScript) o meu tipo de time para ele se sincronizar com meu tempo.. entendes?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11820718/convert-utc-offset-to-timezone-or-date

Answer (score 5):

Parece que você está arranjando problema onde não tem. Segundo a documentação, a função [`time`](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.time.php) do PHP:

> Retorna a hora atual medida no número de segundos desde a Era Unix (January 1 1970 00:00:00 GMT).

E para o JavaScript, [`Date.prototype.getTime()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getTime) funciona igual (mas em milissegundos em vez de segundos):

> *The value returned by the getTime() method is the number of milliseconds since 1 January 1970 00:00:00 UTC.*

As duas funções já funcionam em sincronia. Portanto:

```
// Em JS:
var agora = new Date().getTime();
```

```
// Em PHP:
$agora = time() * 1000;
// Ou, com mais precisão:
// $agora = microtime(true) * 1000;
```

Comment: A hora varia consoante a hora local, tanto do cliente como do servidor.

Comment: @IsmaelMiguel Não varia, não nesse formato.

Comment: Qual é o resultado de correr `new Date(1429760063270)`? Aqui a data e a hora é a do comentário, com cerca de 2m de diferença.

Comment: Ismael, seu servidor ou cliente devem estar atrasados.

Comment: Bfavaretto, não sabia que o time era GMT 0:00 sempre.

Comment: @IsmaelMiguel Na hora de imprimir a data no console, o JS formata o valor, e só nesse momento leva em conta o timezone. Mas o número de milissegundos desde 1/1/1970 0:00:00 UTC independe disso. O tempo desde esse momento é o mesmo em qualquer timezone, pois o momento é fixo, num timezone pré-definido.

Comment: Peço desculpas entao. Mas no PHP, um timestamp de `-3600` vai dar essa data nos Açores, mas não em Portugal continental. No entanto, um timestamp de `3600` vai ser essa data em Portugal continental, mas vai ser diference em Espanha.

Comment: o timestamp representa a data no fuso 0:00, mas as outras funções que vão fazer a impressão/formatação irão considerar o fuso local.

Comment: @IsmaelMiguel É isso que o Édipo disse, o timestamp tem fuso fixo, enquanto as datas formatadas podem levar em conta a configurão local do servidor ou do cliente. A sugestão da minha resposta é usar os somente timestamps para fins de comparação/sincronização.

Comment: @ÉdipoCostaRebouças Peço desculpas pela minha interpretação incorrecta.

Comment: A resposta está correta, mas caso o time esteja sendo gerado errado basta setar o time zone para qual vc precisa, No linux vc pode alterar configurar isto usando este comando "dpkg-reconfigure tzdata"

Answer (score 3):

Para retornar qual é o timezone atual, você pode usar o `getTimezoneOffset`.

```
var timezoneoffset = new Date().getTimezoneOffset();
```

Isso vai retornar a diferença em minutos da hora local e da hora UTC (0:00).

Esses minutos consideram horário de verão também.

Ao invés de usar isso, sugiro a você usar o UTC no backend e frontend,

O JavaScript tem suporte para pegar a sua data e hora local e converter para o timezone UTC, por exemplo:

Por exemplo,

```
var timestamp = new Date().getTime();
```

Vai retornar um timestamp com base no time zone UTC (0:00)

```
var d = new Date(1429016291946);
```

ou

```
var d = new Date();
d.setTime(1429016291946);
```

Vai montar um date a partir do timestamp. Coloquei as duas formas pois não encontrei documentação sobre a primeira, embora funcione.

No PHP, a função `time` retorna um timestamp no fuso 0:00.

O JavaScript trabalha com timestamp em milisegundos e o PHP com segundos, em algum momento do seu código você vai ter que truncar o valor ou multiplicar por 1000, normalizando para o javascript ou PHP.

Referências

- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8655515/get-utc-time-in-php
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8047616/get-a-utc-timestamp-in-javascript
- http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_gettimezoneoffset.asp
- http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_obj_date.asp
- http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_settime.asp

Comment: Ou então utilizar `gmdate('T')`, que tambem retorna um *timestamp* baseado em GMT +00:00.

Comment: Agora, se você for imprimir datas com PHP, você realmente tem que descobrir o timezone do usuário.

Comment: Estão a faltar comentários. Mas corre lá `new Date(1429788190538)` e vê o resultado. Quase de certeza que não vai ser `"Thu Apr 23 2015 12:23:00 GMT+0100 (Hora de Verão de GMT)"`.

Comment: `Thu Apr 23 2015 08:23:10 GMT-0300 (E. South America Standard Time)`, no console, printou conforme minha hora local.

Comment: Tenta usar dessa forma, `var d = new Date(); d.setTime(1429788190538);` não achei muito documentação falando de passar o timestamp direto no construtor.

Comment: Portanto, a interpretação do timestamp varia. O que o O.P. quer é que **não** varie. E a documentação está aqui: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date e aqui: http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_dates.asp

Comment: A interpretação no javascript é para você imprimir a data de forma localizada, esse comportamento esta correto.

Comment: Então a resposta é simples: `var time=new Date(<?=gmdate('t')?>)` ou `var time=new Date(<?=gmmktime()?>)`. Para ter o tempo em GMT. UTC tem base no GMT. A diferença é que o UTC já conta com a mudança de hora.

Comment: então, de sua resposta.

Answer (score 2):

Creio que a função que procura seja [date_default_timezone_set](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.date-default-timezone-set.php)

Exemplo de uso:

```
date_default_timezone_set('America/Sao_Paulo');
```

[Nesse link](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/timezones.php), você encontra os Timezones suportados.

Leia mais sobre, na documentação.

Abraço

Comment: faltou só falar da parte do JavaScript

Comment: explique melhor o seu código, está um pouco vago o que quer fazer com javascript.

Answer (score 1):

Não é necessário muito código.

Aliás, com uma linha dá para resolver o problema de uma vez:

```
var time=new Date(<?=gmmktime()?>000) //Equivalente a <?php echo gmmktime();?>
var time=new Date(<?=gmdate('t')?>000) //Produz o mesmo resultado
```

O `000` é necessário porque o PHP retorna o tempo em segundos, enquanto o Javascript espera o tempo em milisegundos. Adicionando `000` ao fim do numero (ou multiplicar por 1000) resolve a diferença.

Para obter a hora, com base na hora do servidor, sem ter um `setInterval();`, são necessárias algumas alterações:

```
var time=new Date(<?=gmmktime()?>000); //hora do servidor
var time_dif=(new Date())-time; //subtrai a diferença em milisegundos em relação às duas datas

/* [... algum tempo depois ...] */

var server_time=new Date(); //cria uma nova data
server_time.setTime(server_time-time_diff); //subtrai a diferença
```

Não é necessário muito mais do que isto.

Comment: Você esta esquecendo da diferença de precisão lembrada em todas as outras respostas.

Comment: Deve ser uns milisegundos. Mas se a precisão é assim tão importante, o O.P. deveria arranjar um relogio de quartzo ligado ao computador e aceder à hora a um tempo constante. Depois, esse tempo tinha de ser enviado através da internet com uma latência constante e ser feita a subtracção. Tirando isso, isto chega.

Comment: Você testou seu código?

Comment: O que você esta fazendo é cortar os 3 últimos números de um timestamp, se você fizer isso com PHP você acha que vai funcionar? Pois você esta fazendo isso com o JavaScript. Depois de imprimir o timestamp, adicione `000` , exemplo `<?=time()?>000` que ai sim vai funcionar.

Comment: @ÉdipoCostaRebouças Esqueci que o PHP retorna o tempo em segundos. Já está corrigido.