# Como atualizar timezone do PHP com javascript usando a função Date.getTimezoneOffset?

Tags: php, javascript

Estou a obter o `TMZ` do usuario final com este código:

```
TMZ = new Date().getTimezoneOffset()
```

para mim ele retorna `180` e este número eu envio para o servidor, para que ele ajuste a hora dele com a minha, mas a função `date_default_timezone_set` não usa números, como posso ajudar usando o numero retornado pela função JavaScript?

Comment: Qual é o timezone do servidor?

Comment: Não resolve seu problema (na verdade, resolve, mas não é a resposta que você procura), mas essa lib pode te ajudar: http://pellepim.bitbucket.org/jstz/.

Comment: @Sergio o timezone do servidor é irrelevante, ele tem que se adaptar ao do usuário, mas no caso ele está usando o de Brasilia.

Comment: @EduardoSilva achei interessante, vou esperar o Sergio opinar..

Comment: @Elaine cada usuário tem 1 servidor? ou o servidor é seu e sabe o seu timezone?

Comment: @Sergio nao, o usuario apenas precisa enviar seu tmz para o servidor para que o servidor retorne com a hora correta..

Comment: Se entendi você quer ajustar a hora do servidor através de algo no front-end? É isto?

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento obtendo algo do front end para adaptar a hora do servidor. Por exemplo, estou no Brasil mas o servidor é alemão, então alguma coisa do front end deverá ser enviada pro servidor para que ele ajuste a hora junto a mim (front end)

Answer (score 1):

O PHP (lado do servidor) trabalha no *timezone* defenido por tí, ou o default do servidor caso não definas tu. E se o código estiver como deve ser será 1 unico *timezone* independentemente de onde o cliente está.

O JavaScript (lado do cliente) tabalha com o *timezone* onde o cliente está, que na maior parte dos casos é o *timezone* que o cliente tem configurado no seu sistema operativo/browser.

**Há maneira de ambos cliente e servidor falarem na mesma lingua/timezone?**

**Sim, há, o UTC.** No JavaScript podes usar `.getTime()` para dar o numero de milisegundos desde 1 de janeiro de 1970 na timezone UTC. Isto é o segredo pois se o servidor também estiver a usar UTC, então estão a usar a mesma referência.

**Como saber a variação horária do cliente relativo ao UTC?**

Para isto não é preciso ir ao servidor. Podes saber a diferença entre o UTC e a região onde o utilizador está podes usar:

```
var agora = new Date();
var diferenca = agora.getTimezoneOffset() * 60 * 1000; // milisegundos
// -7200000 ms no meu caso (Suécia)
```

Comment: Sim, eu defino meu servidor ao timezone UTC, e a diferença entre o UTC e o timezone do usuário é enviada ao servidor, como fazer o servidor considerar a diferença do usuario para com o servidor (UTC) sempre que ele enviar uma mensagem que contenha `time(), date()..` para aquele usuário X?

Comment: @Elaine se sabes a diferença que o usuário tem, em minutos por exemplo, podes fazer `$horaCliente = time() + ($difCliente * 60);` e assim ficas com um timestamp em segundos. É isso que procuras?

Comment: Acho que entendi, basta fazer a conversao.. Sim o que eu procuro é adequar a hora do servidor (momentaneamente para a resposta de um request) com a do cliente

Comment: @Elaine ok, diz se precisares de mais ajuda. Caso sim dá-me um exemplo concreto do que estás a fazer para eu responder mais concreto também.

Comment: Perdao, era um erro de definiçao, achei banal e removi. Obrigada!

Answer (score 0):

Respondi para outra pessoa sobre um pergunta bem parecida com essa.

O que indiquei para ela foi usar o timezone UTC, pois o javascript converte o horario local para UTC, e UTC para Local, e o PHP consegue trabalhar com UTC.

Veja: [Sincronia do time() PHP e JavaScript](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/58243/sincronia-do-time-php-e-javascript/58247#58247)

Answer (score 0):

Se entendi bem quer atualizar o horário do servidor (pela timezone), se está no Brasil e o servidor é Americano (US) quer que os scripts rodem com o horário do Brasil.

Existem dois caminhos a se tomar, o primeiro e o que eu mais recomendo é não mudar o horário do servidor "diretamente", quero dizer pode alterar o timezone sim, mas em todas funções de registro, como inserir dados no banco prefira usar UTC (ou GMT) e no momento de ler os dados do banco você ajustaria para o timezone do usuário.

### Por que getTimezoneOffset retorna 180?

Vou primeiro explicar o motivo do 180, quando esta no brasil e rodamos o comando:

```
  new Date().getTimezoneOffset();
```

Ele irá retornar `180`, este valor deve ser dividido por `60`, isso irá dar o numero `3`, o Brasil e referencia ao UTC esta `-3` horas. Então o 180 esta correto, mas isto eu fiz em horas, você pode usar o 180 fazendo o script ser -180 segundos, mas fica um pouco mais difícil talvez, pois teria que usar `gmmktime` do PHP combinado com `gmdate` (funções que trabalham com GMT) ou então usar `DateTime::modify` que pode ser mais fácil (veja o exemplo abaixo).

### Ajustar timezone com javascript

Basicamente (se for automático ou não) você pode fazer algo como uma atualização via ajax:

```
<?php session_start(); ?>

<?php if (empty($_SESSION['timezonesec'])): ?>

    <script>
    (function () {
        var oReq = new XMLHttpRequest();
        var tz = -(new Date().getTimezoneOffset());

        oReq.open("GET", "/update-timezone.php?sec=" + tz, true);

        oReq.onreadystatechange = function()
        {
            if (oReq.readyState === 4) {
                console.log(oReq.responseText);
            }
        };

        oReq.send(null);
    })();
    </script>

<?php endif; ?>
```

O arquivo `update-timezone.php` ficaria algo como:

```
<?php
session_start();

if (!empty($_GET['sec'])) {
    $_SESSION['timezonesec'] = $_GET['sec'];
}
```

Então crie um arquivo "global" (se já tiver um basta coloar o UTC no topo) que contenha algo como:

**global.php**

```
<?php
session_start();
date_default_timezone_set('UTC');

if (empty($_SESSION['timezonesec'])) {
     //Emite "erro" (exceção se não conseguir configurar a timezone)
     throw new Exception('Timezone não pode ser definida');
}

$tzs = $_SESSION['timezonesec'];
$sec = ($tzs < 0 ? '-' : '+') . $tzs;

//Ajusta pra plural ou singular (realmente não sei se isto faz diferença para o php)
$sp  = ' second' . ($tzs < -1 || $tzs > 1 ? 's' : "");

define('TIMEZONE_SECONDS', $sec . $sp);
```

E os demais scripts você pode usar a classe [DateTime](http://php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php) (ela pode ser mais fãcil de trabalhar que a função `date`):

```
<?php
require_once 'global.php';

$time = new DateTime();
$time->modify(TIMEZONE_SECONDS);

echo $date->format('Y-m-d h:i:s');
```

Só que há um problema que pode atrapalhar, o computador do usuário pode estar com alguma configuração invalida (até mesmo por falta de bateria).

Do meu ponto de vista o melhor é sempre gravar em UTC (ou GMT) e ajustar o horário na hora de exibir os dados, se for um usuário autenticado você pode dar a opção dele mesmo escolher a timezone desejada (acho que muitos sites fazem desta maneira), o usuário seleciona o país e o ajuste é automático (como o facebook).

### Ajustar timezone usando apenas o back-end

Algo que seria mais seguro contra falhas se quiser a detecção automática que encontrei no [SOEN](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23551583/1518921) seria usar a API do site maxmind, baixe ambos:

1. http://www.maxmind.com/download/geoip/api/php/php-latest.tar.gz
2. http://geolite.maxmind.com/download/geoip/database/GeoLiteCity.dat.gz

Depois crie um arquivo global.php assim:

```
<?php
session_start();

//Pega o IP do usuário (proxies podem alterar isto)
$ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];

if (empty($_SESSION['timezone:' . $ip])) {
    //Le os dados, o GeoLiteCity.dat é o arquivo que você baixou
    $gi = geoip_open("GeoLiteCity.dat", GEOIP_STANDARD);
    $record = geoip_record_by_addr($gi, $ip);

    if(isset($record)) {
        //Usa a função da API do maxmind e salva em uma sessão
        $_SESSION['timezone:' . $ip] = get_time_zone($record->country_code, ($record->region!='') ? $record->region : 0);
    }
}

if (empty($_SESSION['timezone:' . $ip])) {
     //Emite "erro" (exceção se não conseguir configurar a timezone)
     throw new Exception('Timezone não pode ser definida');
}

date_default_timezone_set($_SESSION['timezone:' . $ip]);
```

E adicione e todos seus arquivos isto:

```
<?php
require_once 'global.php';
```